# How to decode nested objects with ts.data.json

Tags: typescript, jsondecoder

I'm trying to use the example at https://github.com/joanllenas/ts.data.json to decode and validate a json payload in Typescript. This works ok, but I want to use this with nested data, for example a User has an Address.

I've tried using JsonDecoder.object as the type for Address, but this doesn't work. My IDE (IntelliJ) says I need a DecoderObject rather than a Decoder. Can anyone recommend how I do this?

```
type Address = {
    street: string;
    town: string; 
    postcode: string;
};


type User = {
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
    address: Address;
};

const addressDecoder = JsonDecoder.object<User>(
    {
        street: JsonDecoder.string,
        town: JsonDecoder.string,
        postcode: JsonDecoder.string
    },
    'User'
);


const userDecoder = JsonDecoder.object<User>(
    {
        firstname: JsonDecoder.string,
        lastname: JsonDecoder.string,
        address: JsonDecoder.object(addressDecoder, "AddressDecoder")
    },
    'User'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

First things first: in your example, both of the decoders have the same and the same name. Anyway, it's a simple thing to fix.

Answering your question: after you'll fix the above, then you should replace `address` decoder with decoderObject as you can see below:

```js
const addressDecoder = JsonDecoder.object<Address>(
    {
        street: JsonDecoder.string,
        town: JsonDecoder.string,
        postcode: JsonDecoder.string
    },
    'Address'
);

const userDecoder = JsonDecoder.object<User>(
    {
        firstname: JsonDecoder.string,
        lastname: JsonDecoder.string,
        address: addressDecoder
    },
    'User'
);
```

and I think it should work correctly.